# MySQL Bulk Insert record lines that failed

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I have a bulk insert operation where errors are ignored. The bulk insert gets it data from a CSV file. The errors would be typical data mismatch errors and not duplication nor "not enough columns in row for insert" kind of errors. The duplicate records are handled separately in a pre-processor. However, there can always be an error when a column in the CSV file is of the wrong data type (such as a boolean value in place of a varchar).

Filtering these out would be an overhead and cases like these are minimal since the CSV will be computer generated. However they need to be taken into account. I am carrying out Bulk insert with the Ignore option where any failed insert does not rollback all previous inserts and stops execution.

Is there anyway I can record which lines had an error when the Bulk insert executed itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SHOW WARNINGS` statement to get errors, warnings, and notes occured after insert.